# Create WEBP or GIF from PNGs

Tags: flutter, image, dart, gif

I looked into the `image` package:

Creating an animated GIF from PNGs is not exactly fast if more than a handful of frames are involved.

Is there a performant solution that creates a GIF or WEBP in either Dart or Canvas-Flutter?

(Not looking for an UI solution, just the processing code.)